# Neo4j Start Error: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory

Tags: neo4j

After upgrading from **Neo4j 3.0** to **3.1** (and subsequently 3.2), I get the following error after running `sudo neo4j start`:

```
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 411: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory
```

Nonetheless, *Neo4j is actually running* after running this command.. However, I cannot then stop Neo4j afterwards with `sudo neo4j stop`, as there is no PID.

How can I fix this?

---

**Notes:**

- I upgraded using `sudo apt upgrade`
- It is possible to get around this issue by doing a `sudo mkdir /var/run/neo4j` beforehand, but was hoping there might be a more effective solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using the installation package you should not start/stop with the neo4j script, but use the installed service. Depending on your Ubuntu version that is

```
sudo service neo4j {start|stop|restart}
```

or

```
sudo systemctl {start|stop|restart} neo4j
```

Check http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/ and http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/systemd/ for more information.

Hope this helps,
Tom

P.S. Note that starting/stopping without using the service may have started Neo4j with the wrong user (root instead of neo4j) and files may therefore have the wrong ownership now !

Comment: the operation isnt working, how can i start it manually? also how can i get the PID?